# Error while deploying a node.js app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

There is an error while deploying a node.js app to heroku.

I am beginner. So if you tell me how to fix it, I am so pleased.

I think a module of sharp causes an error.

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        
remote:        > sharp@0.26.3 install /tmp/build_703b3ee2/node_modules/sharp
remote:        > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
remote:        
remote:        internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
remote:          throw err;
remote:          ^
remote:        
remote:        Error: Cannot find module '../internal/parse-options'

remote:        internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
remote:          throw err;
remote:          ^
remote:        
remote:        Error: Cannot find module '../internal/parse-options'

remote:        gyp: Call to 'node -p "require('./lib/libvips').minimumLibvipsVersion"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
remote:        gyp ERR! configure error 

remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1081-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_703b3ee2/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_703b3ee2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_703b3ee2/node_modules/sharp
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok 
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! sharp@0.26.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.26.3 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Is your `node_modules/` tracked? It generally shouldn't be. Untrack it, ignore it, commit, and redeploy.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but `node_modules` is already ignored ;(

Comment: But is it also _committed?_ Git's ignore system only prevents things from being tracked. Once a file is committed, ignoring it does nothing. What does `git ls-files node_modules` give you if you run it from the root of your repository, where the `node_modules/` directory exists?